# Curve fitting a Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, best-fit-curve

Hey everyone I feel like I have a basic question that for some reason I can't figure out

So I have a matrix:

```
A = [1.7764,1.7677,1.7509,1.7352,1.7075,1.6715,1.6043l,1.5199,1.4210,1.3041,1.1756,1.0270,0.8582,0.6910,0.5493,0.3968,0.2187 ];
```

So I want to a find a function for A using a best fit curve.  I know I want to use some kind of:

```
polyfit(A)
```

I have never needed to find an equation of a matrix and im sure it will be a simple one line code that I've been stuck on for longer than I care to admit.

If more information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find a `polyfit`, you need to define a vector for the x-axis against which you are going to plot.  For instance:

```
A_y = [1.7764,1.7677,1.7509,1.7352,1.7075,1.6715,1.6043l,1.5199,1.4210,1.3041,1.1756,1.0270,0.8582,0.6910,0.5493,0.3968,0.2187 ];
A_x = 1:length(A_y);
polyfit(A_x, A_y, <Degree>);
```

Note that you need to substitute `<Degree>` with the degree of the fit you are looking for.

Comment: So that would yield a matrix values that would fit the data.  How would I make that best fit be a function of x?

Comment: The resultant matrix represents a function of x.  For instance, if I were to get [1, 2, 3, 4] as a result, this would be x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4.